# Full credit card photo (front and back) accidentally sent to a customer service, what to do now?

Tags: vpn, credit-card, fraud

The VPN customer service told me to edit the photo so they could only see the beginning and ending of the credit number and I accidentally sent the full photo of the front and back.

Am I screwed?

Comment: How did you transmit it to them. Unencrypted email over wifi at Starbucks? A secure HTTPS upload form? Have they securely deleted it yet? Have they **really** securely deleted it yet?

Comment: @Jedi Suggested duplicate is about disclosing front, this is about disclosing front *and back*. Minor difference, so perhaps varranted as a duplicate anyway,

Answer (score 6):

Immediately call your bank's Lost and Stolen credit card number, found on the back of your credit card.  Tell them what happened, and they will take the appropriate action.

Comment: Some cards like Discover card have built in "Freeze It' on app and discover.com where you can freeze the card immediately while you are on call with customer service to block completely.